# Rails 6 select random ActiveRecord object for each category

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I've got TestQuestion model where I store survey questions with predefined and hardcoded categories:

```
CATEGORIES = %w[Q1 Q2 Q3 Q4]
```

I want to present to user randomly selected one published question from each category of questions. I was trying something like:

```
CATEGORIES.each { |c| TestQuestion.where(category: c).random }
```

But I'm getting an error: `NoMethodError (undefined method random' for <TestQuestion::ActiveRecord_Relation:0x00007f091cf1ac08>)`

Besides I think it's a smelly code. Is there any better way to do that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

there is no random function but you can do (depending on your database)

Postgresql or SQLite:

```rb
TestQuestion.where(category: c).order('RANDOM()').first
```

MySQL:

```rb
TestQuestion.where(category: c).order('RAND()').first
```

you can also use Arel

```rb
TestQuestion.where(category: c).order(Arel.sql('RANDOM()')).first
```

*note: that if your DB is large and there is a performance issue you might want to `limit(1)` then `first`*

you are also using `each.` which will return the original object you are iterating through, you need to switch to `map.`

Comment: If I assign it to a variable it will return an array of categories ` ["Q1", "Q2", "Q3", "Q4", "Q"]` instead of AR objects

Comment: @mr_muscle updated answer, you should switch to `map.` instead of `each.`